# Why is an RSA public key BITWRAP-ed in ASN.1 DER encoding?

Tags: rsa, openssl, asn.1

While playing around with creating an RSA public key, and decoding it using a home brew ASN.1 decoder, I ran into the fact that the public key is BITWRAP-ed. BITWRAP seems to be an OpenSSL modifier, and I wonder why it is needed, what the rationale is?

[This page](http://certificate.fyicenter.com/2224_OpenSSL_ans1parse_-BITWRAP_and_OCTWRAP_Modifiers.html) describes *what* BITWRAP is but not *why* it is needed.

Why can't $n$ and $e$ be encoded in a regular non-BITWRAP-ed ASN.1 sequence?

Below example shows the BITWRAP modifier in an ASN1 definition (copied from [OpenSSL docs](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/ASN1_generate_nconf.html)):

```
asn1=SEQUENCE:pubkeyinfo

# BITWRAP here
[pubkeyinfo]
algorithm=SEQUENCE:rsa_alg
pubkey=BITWRAP,SEQUENCE:rsapubkey

[rsa_alg]
algorithm=OID:rsaEncryption
parameter=NULL

[rsapubkey]
n=INTEGER:0xBB6FE79432CC6EA2D8F970675A5A87BFBE1AFF0BE63E879F2AFFB93644\
D4D2C6D000430DEC66ABF47829E74B8C5108623A1C0EE8BE217B3AD8D36D5EB4FCA1D9
e=INTEGER:0x010001
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a Subject Public Key Info structure defined by the [X.509 standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1):

```
   SubjectPublicKeyInfo  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
        algorithm            AlgorithmIdentifier,
        subjectPublicKey     BIT STRING  }
```

The reason it's BITWRAP-ed is that the structure of the wrapped public key depends on the `algorithm`. It could be a RSA public key as you described, but it could be an elliptic curve or DSA public key too. Without wrapping, the ASN.1 parser would need to be aware of the `algorithm` it has just parsed to know how to parse the `subjectPublicKey`, which is cumbersome. With wrapping, it just parses the whole structure and `subjectPublicKey` can be interpreted later.

(The big question for me it's why it uses a BIT STRING instead of a OCTET STRING...)

Comment: My guess on the big question: there could be algorithms which public key is a single component (rather than constructed), and that component's natural type could be an integer, octet string or bitstring depending on algorithm (e.g. bitstring  would be a natural choice for the public-key of a cryptosystem based on the DLP problem in $GF(2^{9941})$, which used to make sense). Everyone agrees on how to decode an octet string and its length from a bitstring, and a (big-endian) integer from a bitstring. But various conventions exist to decode a bitstring and its length from the other two.